# Dividing a .yml file up

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, yaml, edit

I need to break down .yml files into 3 parts: Header, Working (the part I need to edit), and footer. The header is everything that comes before the 'Resource: ' block, and the footer is everything after the resource block. I essentially need to create code that creates 3 lists, dictionaries, strings, whatever works, that holds these three sections of the YAML file, then allows me to run more code against the working piece, then concatenate all of them together at the end and produce the new document with the same indentations. No changes should be made to the header or the tail.

Note: I've looked up everything about yaml parsing and whatnot, but cannot seem to implement the advice I've found effectively. A solution that does not involve importing yaml would be preferred, but if you must, please explain what is really going on with the import yaml code so I can understand what I'm messing up.

Comment: Can you post a really simple `yaml` format that you're looking at and a simple `output`? That way it's a bit easier for us to see what you're looking at

Answer (score 0):

Files that contain one or more YAML documents (in short: a YAML file, which, since
Sept. 2006, has been recommended to have the extension `.yaml`), are
text files and can be concatenated from parts as such. The only requirement being
that in the end you have a text file that is a valid YAML file.

The easiest is of course to have the Header and footer in separate
files for that, but as you are talking about multiple YAML files this
soon becomes unwieldy. It is however always possible to do some basic
parsing of the file contents.

Since your Working part starts with `Resource:`, and you indicate 3
lists or dictionaries (you cannot have three strings at the root of a
YAML document). The root level data structure of your YAML document
needs to be a either a *mapping*, and everything else, except for the
keys to that mapping need to be indented (in theory it only needs to
be indented more, but in practise this almost always means that the
keys are not indented), Like (`m.yaml`):

```
# header
a: 1
b:
  - 2
  - c: 3    # end of header
Resource:
# footer
c: 
d: "the end"   # really
```

or the root level needs to be a sequence (`s.yaml`):

```
# header
- a: 1
  b:
  - 2
  - c: 3
- 42         # end of header
- Resource:
# footer
- c: 
  d: "the end"  # really
```

both can easily be split without loading the YAML, here is the example code for doing so for
the file with the root level mapping:

```
from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

inf = Path('m.yaml')
header = []  # list of lines
resource = [] 
footer = []
for line in inf.open():
    if not resource:
        if line.startswith('Resource:'):  # check if we are at end of the header
            resource.append(line)
            continue
        header.append(line)
        continue
    elif not footer:
        if not line or line[0] == ' ':   # still in the resource part
            resource.append(line)
            continue
    footer.append(line)

# you now have lists of lines for the header and the footer
# define the new data structure for the resource this is going to be a single key/value dict
upd_resource = dict(Resource=['some text', 'for the resource spec', {'a': 1, 'b': 2}])

# write the header lines, dump the resource lines, write the footer lines

outf = Path('out.yaml')

with outf.open('w') as out:
    out.write(''.join(header))
    yaml = YAML()
    yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=2, offset=0)  # the default values
    yaml.dump(upd_resource, out)
    out.write(''.join(footer))

print(outf.read_text())
```

this gives:

```
# header
a: 1
b:
  - 2
  - c: 3    # end of header
Resource:
- some text
- for the resource spec
- a: 1
  b: 2
# footer
c: 
d: "the end"   # really
```

---

Doing the same while parsing the YAML file is not more difficult. The following automitcally handles
both cases (whether the root level is a mapping or a sequence):

```
from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

inf = Path('s.yaml')
upd_resource_val = ['some text', 'for the resource spec', {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
outf = Path('out.yaml')


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=2, offset=0)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(inf)
if isinstance(data, dict):
    data['Resource'] = upd_resource_val
else:  # assume a list, 
    for item in data:  # search for the item which has as value a dict with key Resource
        try:
            if 'Resource' in item:
                item['Resource'] = upd_resource_val
                break
        except TypeError:
            pass
yaml.dump(data, outf)
```

This creates the following `out.yaml`:

```
# header
- a: 1
  b:
  - 2
  - c: 3
- 42         # end of header
- Resource:
  - some text
  - for the resource spec
  - a: 1
    b: 2
# footer
- c:
  d: "the end"  # really
```

If the `m.yaml` file had been the input, the output would have
been exactly the same as with the text based "concatenation" example code.

Comment: Of course if you know all the files have a mapping **or** all the files have a sequence at the top, you can simplify the last example code by removing the root level `if` statement.